# es6 : how to import const after export?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I apologise for my lack of knowledge. I want to import a const value inside a file. I have two files Home.js and styles.js in the same directory.

> Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles';

const Home = (props) => {

    const HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT = 200;

}

export { HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT };
export default Home;
```

> And in styles.js

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT } from './Home';

export default StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        height: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT
    }
});
```

but i am getting this error

> Can't find variable : HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT

how can i access that variable in styles.js?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try:

> Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles';

export const HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT = 200;

const Home = props => <h1>Home</h1>;

export default Home;
```

> styles.js

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT } from './Home';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    height: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT,
  },
});
```

Your `HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT` needs to be within the `Home.js` file but outside of the `Home` Component. You can read about it here: [Javascript Scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: Are you sure both .Home.js and styles.js are as wiring ? maybe Home.js Styles.js? both capitalized ?

Comment: i wish it was like that. but its not. maybe its not working because they're import from each other at the same time. Could this be the issue?

Comment: have you got Teamviewer?

Comment: i got anydesk. here is a gist containing the original two files https://gist.github.com/basith374/59f7178304c133311d65fb527eea7bae

Comment: what does console.log(HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT) print?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127946/discussion-between-bazi-and-ilan-hasanov).

Answer (score 53):

You should probably structure your code in a completely different manner.

A good rule is to keep all constants in a separate file, away from all Views.

Try creating a file for all App Constants.  `Constants.js` is a good choice.

Then put constants in like this:

```
const Constants = {
  HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT: 200,
  OTHER_THINGS: 'whatever'
}
export default Constants
```

Then you can import your constants wherever you need them.

```
import Constants from '../Folder/Constants'
```

and use like such

```
const x = Constants.HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT
```

Comment: for properties it should be  : not  =

Comment: Any idea how to use async function and export it?

Answer (score 3):

This is just function scoping rule!

```
// Outer scope
const Home = (props) => {
    // Inner scope
    const HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT = 200;

}

console.log(HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT); // Uncaught ReferenceError: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT is not defined
```

You don't have access to HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT in the outer scope. So when you try to export it, it just returns an error.

Try with this:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles';

const HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT = 200;

const Home = (props) => {     
    // ...
}

export { HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT };
export default Home;
```

Now in styles.js:

```
import { HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT } from './Home';
```

Comment: its not working. says HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT is undefined, inside styles.js

Comment: Please, can you show me styles.js ? Do you import HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT from Home ?

Comment: You could also do Home.HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT = 200; after the const Home [...] and in styles.js: import Home from './Home'; console.log(Home.HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT);

Comment: Any circular module references?